# Search query doesn't return all the databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api

I'm having problem to get all the Database entries when I call the API call.
When I call it just return me a few databases.

```
async function getDatabases(item){
      if(item.object == 'database')
            console.log(item)
}

async function listAllDatabases(){
    const response = await notion.search({
        sort: {
            direction: 'ascending',
            timestamp: 'last_edited_time'.
        },
     });
    response.results.forEach(getDatabases)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to share those databases with your integration in Notion first.